# Comparing 2 columns in same database table in a case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 4 columns

1. IndexNo  - Int datatype
2. CaseID - varchar datatype
3. Property varchar datatype
4. RecordAddedDate datetime

The requirement is to add a timestamp to column 4 when column2 and column3 has values.(ie when records entered).

Note : Column1 and Column2 has values whereas Column3 is empty (Nulls)
Column3 values are entered runtime.

I tried something like this

```
insert into tbl_valuation6(Property,RecordAddedDate)
select Property,
case when 
tbl_valuation6.Property is not null
THEN GETDATE()
ELSE null
END AS RecordAddedDate
from tbl_valuation6
```

Error i am  getting is:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Property'.

Comment: You explained the requirement (sample data and expected output would help), but you forgot to ask a question. Please show us what you tried and why it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I'm still confused what you are really trying to do. in your sql you are inserting a new record, is that what you want to do? Or do you want to update an existing record?

Comment: @AppanaGanesh: this error indicates that `tbl_valuation6` has no column called `Property`. You might want to double check the names of the columns in your table.